# JS check if url contains word or chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

is there anyway to check if window.location.href contains some portions chars or words?

like:

```
if(window.location.href.like("/users") or window.location.href.like("/profile") ){
//do somenthing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.match` and supply a regular expression:

```
if (window.location.href.match(/\/(users|profile)/)) {
  alert('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href.search("something")` is useful

```
if(window.location.href.search(/\/(users|profile)/) != -1) {  // if not found
  // do something
}
```

[**`search()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) return index of first match or `-1` if not found, doesn't return boolean `true/false`

You can also use

```
if(!(/\/("users|profile")/.test(window.location.href))) {  // if not found
  // do something
}
```

**[.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** return boolean value.